# Problem decorating Python stored procedure handler with @functools.cache

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am building a Python stored procedure that will execute a lengthy process and return a result. To improve performance, the handler code will be decorated with `functools.cache` to cache results. The following code is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```
create or replace function get_key(which varchar) returns varchar
language python runtime_version = '3.11'
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
handler = 'get_key'
AS $$
import functools

@functools.cache
def get_key(which):
  if which == 'PN':
    return 'toomanysecrets'
  else:
    return ''
$$;

select get_key('PN');
```

Error is

> Python Interpreter Error:
> AttributeError: 'functools._lru_cache_wrapper' object has no attribute
> '__code__' in function GET_KEY with handler get_key

Answer (score 1):

OK, turns out to have a simple solution: I created an additional function that is wrapped with the cache decorator, and changed the handle function to call it:

```
create or replace function get_key(which varchar) returns varchar
language python runtime_version = '3.11'
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
handler = 'main'
AS $$
import functools

@functools.cache
def get_key(which):
  if which == 'PN':
    return 'toomanysecrets'
  else:
    return ''

def main(which):
  return get_key(which)
$$;
```